Android CameraX failed to write temp file
    private void takePicture() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();


            File file = new File(getContext().getExternalCacheDir() + File.separator + "VISION_" + timestamp + ".jpeg");

            ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
                    file
            ).build();


            imageCapture.takePicture(outputOptions, getExecutor(),
                    new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onImageSaved(ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                            Uri imageFile = outputFileResults.getSavedUri();
                            Log.d("Image", "onImageSaved: Uri=" + imageFile.toString());

                            try {
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getPath());
                                Log.d("Image", "onImageSaved: Bitmap=" + (bitmap != null));

                                if (bitmap != null) {
                                    String base64String = encodeToBase64(bitmap);
                                    Log.d("Base64", "onImageSaved: Base64=" + base64String);

                                    String text = AIUtils.postRequest(userInfo.get("bearer").toString(), base64String);
                                    Log.d("AIUtils", "onImageSaved: Response=" + text);

                                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("Image", "onImageSaved: Failed to decode Bitmap from file");
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("Image", "onImageSaved: Exception=" + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(ImageCaptureException error) {
                            Log.e("Image", "onError: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
            );
        } else {
            requestCameraPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
    }

I need help I'm getting failed to write temp file, I've tried adding external permission, etc..
Which is not even required on android 10+
Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?
I'm expecting the app to correctly save the temp file.

Is the error coming from CameraX logcat?
